# DropDownListFor ASP MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am getting this error "CS1928:

> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does
>   not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and the best extension
>   method overload
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)'
>   has some invalid arguments"

My controller looks like this

```
    public class IndexController : Controller
{
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
               EpfeSelectScreen model = new EpfeSelectScreen();

               var b = (from a in dbEntitiesErste.CONFIG_APPLICATIONS
                               orderby a.APPLICATION_ID
                               select new EPFE.CustomDataObjects.CustomObjects
                               {
                                   Text = a.APPLICATION_NAME,
                                   Value = a.APPLICATION_ID
                               });

               model.Application = b.OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList();

               return View(model); 




       }
}
```

My model is this

```
    public class EpfeSelectScreen
{ 
    public string Search { get; set; }
    public string selectedApplication { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Country { get; set; }
    public List<CustomObjects> Application { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> MetaData { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> References { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ReferencedBy { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> TreeView { get; set; }       

    public EpfeSelectScreen()
    {
        Country = new List<SelectListItem>();
        Application = new List<CustomObjects>();           
        References = new List<SelectListItem>();
        ReferencedBy = new List<SelectListItem>();
        TreeView = new List<SelectListItem>();        
    }
}
```

My CustomObjects is this

```
    public class CustomObjects
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public short Value { get; set; }
}
```

I have one record in my model.Application, but when that data is passed to my View i get that error.

And my View looks like this

```
@model EPFE.Controllers.EpfeSelectScreen
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedApplication, Model.Application)
```

How to solve this problem? What am i doing wrong? I get the same error when i try to use ListBoxFor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DropDownListFor` takes a `SelectList` as a second argument while you are passing a `List`.

You could have something like the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedApplication, 
                     new SelectList(Model.Application,"Value","Text"))
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I didn't know that part with SelectList and List. You helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

For Adding items to drop down you can use ViewData for passing values to the dropdown.

in the controller:
you can have scenario like

```
       IList<SelectListItem> SelectedOptions = new List<SelectListItem>();
        IList<Options> DropDownOptions = new List<Options>();
        //Add items to this shipping
        foreach (var item in DropDownOptions)
        {
            SelectListItem sliItem = new SelectListItem();
            string optionText = item._name;
            sliItem.Value = item._value.ToString();
            sliItem.Text = optionText;
            SelectedOptions.Add(sliItem);
        }
        ViewData["Option"] = SelectedOptions;
```

and in the view you can simply use

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Option", ViewData["Option"] as SelectList)
```

while submitting the form if you are using the class, do remember to put a string property with the name option in the class so that you can use it in the controller also the selected value when the form is submitted.